# Why isn't Matlab/Octave reading in the entire 14 bits of my .NEF raw files?

Tags: nikon, raw, bit-depth

I am using a Nikon D5200. I intend to do some image processing on the raw images shot with the camera. But I am encountering a problem when I read the raw images using GNU Octave. Rather than giving bit depth of 16 (since the .NEF are shot at 14-bit depth), the result is just a 8-bit array. What might be the problem?

> imfinfo("/media/karthikeyan/3434-3531/DCIM/100D5200/DSC_1094.NEF")
>
> ans =
>
> scalar structure containing the fields:
>
> Filename = /media/karthikeyan/3434-3531/DCIM/100D5200/DSC_1094.NEF
>
> FileModDate = 10-Oct-2016 18:10:02
>
> FileSize =  26735420
>
> Format = DCRAW
>
> FormatVersion =
>
> Width =  6036
>
> Height =  4020
>
> BitDepth =  8
>
> ColorType = truecolor

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Octave 4.0.3.

Comment: Could be related to this question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/why-are-my-14-bit-raw-files-being-saved-as-8-bit-on-my-computer

Comment: What does `exiftool DCS_1094.NEF | grep -i bit` tell you?

Comment: @chili555 Here is what your command tells me - `exiftool DSC_1094.NEF | grep -i bit
Bits Per Sample                 : 14`

Comment: That suggests that the RAW file is, indeed 14-bit but that there is an issue with Octave.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page:

[Tips for reading a camera raw file into MATLAB](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/03/08/tips-for-reading-a-camera-raw-file-into-matlab/)

According to this you are actually reading the thumbnail image and not the RAW file itself. You must convert the .NEF to .DNG and then utilize a Tiff class.

Comment: If the file size is 26 Mb, then I doubt he is reading the thumbnail.

Comment: @chili555 Is that the compressed or decompressed size?

Comment: @MichaelClark How do it check that? I guess its compressed based on official tech-specs.  Or  did you mean something like zip?

Comment: @karthikeyan I don't know. I don't use MATLAB. But when it is displayed on your monitor a compressed jpeg has to be decompressed first. The size of the decompressed file will be based on the resolution times the bit depth for each color channel.

Comment: @chili555 I don't work with NEF files but I'm pretty sure they have both a small thumbnail and either a half or full size jpeg embedded in them.

Comment: @MichaelClark They certainly do; however, the file size shown above is clearly 26 Mb, suggesting that the reading is not of *only* the thumbnail but of the entire raw file.

Comment: You have to be careful with prepackaged software which claims to read TIFF -- many of them automatically clip to 8-bit data.  Depending on what code you've got, you may have to "roll your own" binary file reader and work with the datacube (x,y, color planes) you get that way.